# E_INVALIDARG One or more arguments are invalid. dx11 CreateInputLayout

Tags: c++, arguments, directx-11, vertex-shader

I try to create a 3d application, and instancing is working fine with positions. I want to set the color for the instances, and it does not work, I receive a run time error "E_INVALIDARG One or more arguments are invalid.".

```
{
    float4 Pos : POSITION;  // question 1
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 InstancePosition : TEXCOORD1; // instance data - ok
    float3 InstanceColor : COLOR; // question 2 (without it works fine)
};


PS_INPUT VS(VS_INPUT input)
{
    PS_INPUT output = (PS_INPUT)0;
    ...
}

C++ part:
        D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] =
        {
            // data from vertex buffer
            { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0,  D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 } // question 1
            ,{ "TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }

            // data from instance buffer
            ,{ "TEXCOORD", 1, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 1, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, 1 }
            ,{ "COLOR", 1, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 1, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, 1 } // question 2 (without it works fine)
        };
        UINT numElements = ARRAYSIZE(layout);

        hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateInputLayout(layout, numElements, pVSBlob->GetBufferPointer(),
            pVSBlob->GetBufferSize(), &g_pVertexLayout2); // <== error: "E_INVALIDARG One or more arguments are invalid."
```

Question 1: in VS it says "float4 Pos : POSITION;", however C++ code is ""POSITION", DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT" (=12 byte, float3), why does it work? (it works perfectly well)
Question 2: I am unable to add other data to instance (Color).
Question 3: I also realized, that the name in VS and C++ can be different, as you can see in VS they are: "POSITION, TEXCOORD0, TEXCOORD1", in C++: "POSITION, TEXCOORD, TEXCOORD". Any ide why? I thought they must be the same VS/C++. 
I am stuck for weeks - any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: As you are new to Direct3D 11, you may want to take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit for DX11](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, at the botom there is an explanation for the issue, based on it, I could fix the code. The final - and working - one is:

```
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] =
        {
            // data from vertex buffer
            { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0,  D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
            ,{ "TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }

            // data from instance buffer
            ,{ "TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 1, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, 1 }
            ,{ "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 1, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, 1 }

        };
```

The problem was the second parameter (index) 0 iso 1. I should have been more careful reading this great article: https://www.braynzarsoft.net/viewtutorial/q16390-34-aabb-cpu-side-frustum-culling